# Does Firebase's UI Auth connect with Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Before I learn Firebase's UI Auth, I want to know if it does the following:

I would've thought one purpose of having an authentication system was so that it could provide the user with a personalised experience of the website.

For instance, once signing in, the user is added to Firebase's Realtime Database. The user's 'name property' is the one it gives to sign up with. An element's content contains the message: 'Hello 'username'.

Does UI Auth connect to Firebase's Realtime Database to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,firebase does not do such a thing.You must add users to a realtime database by yourself.
Once signed in,you can access user properties for example(username and email). After that,you have the freedom how do you want to manage your users.

---

**EDIT:**

```
//you initialize app with fierebase config
app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
this.auth=app.auth();

//this line return a Promise 
this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(
authUser=>{       /*

                Here you add user to firebase
                you want to use authUser.user.id  as document id
                 You also can access email and password
                  */

                    
                });
```

Here is a link that might be helpful:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: Thanks. Would you be able to point out where (in the docs or perhaps a tutorial) you can access a user's username or email when they sign in via the 'email' option?